# drag and drop in horizontalscrollview android

Tags: android, android-view

I have my own horizontalScrollView and inside it a RelativeLayout (vertical), inside this RelativeLayout three LinearLayout(horizontal). Inside each LinearLayout I have some ImageView.

How can I drag  this imageView and drop it into another layout that is not inside the HorizontalScrollView?

I am working with android (2.3.3) api level 10, and I found the way to drag and drop an item, but not like I asked.
This is a part of my xml that concerns the HorizontalScrollView: the ImageView are added programatically into the three LinearLayout.

```
       <com.toj.hungrynow.HorizontalScrollViewEx
            android:id="@+id/listItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/barSettings"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeContainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/topContainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/middleContainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/topContainer"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/middleContainer"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.toj.hungrynow.HorizontalScrollViewEx>
```

Thanks